# NSDictionary in NSMutableArray ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I've a `NSMutableArray` array having `NSDictionary` keys as:

```
NSMutableArray *arr=@[@{@"A":@{@"user":@"obj1",@"friend":@"obj2"}}];
```

No I want to add objects to this `NSMutableArray`.

**My Code:**

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        NSString *user = @"A"+i;
        for(int i=0;i<50;i++) {
            NSString *friend1 = @"B"+i;
 NSString *friend2 = @"C"+i;
 NSString *friend3 = @"D"+i;

        }
    }
         NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
  NSString *y=  [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSLog(@"%@",y);
```

Desired Output:

```
{"A":[{"user":"A1","friend":"B1"},{"user":"A1","friend":"B2"},{"user":"A2","friend":"B1"}]}
```

How can I set my objects in order to achieve desired output.

Comment: Cant you make a string template instead, if its a static format.. and then use stringWithFormat to populate that template? you can iterate through your array and add values to this template.

Comment: seems interesting, please elborate your suggestion with more detail and a piece of code to understand. @Apple_iOS0304

Comment: Little sidenote: `@[]` literal creates an immutable array. I like to use `[@[] mutableCopy]`

Comment: OK, fine. I understand. Now how to store in that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString* singleObjectTemplate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"user\" : \"%@\",\"friend\" : \"%@\"}", user, friend];
NSString* validJsonTemplate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"A\":[%@]}", singleObjectTemplate];
```

Something like this. You can modify it as per your requirement to add multiple entries.

I hope this helps you in some way. Cheers!! :)

**EDIT:**

Suppose you want to add 3 objects to it.

```
NSString *str = @"";
for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
{
   NSString* singleObjectTemplate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"user\" : \"%@\",\"friend\" : \"%@\"}", user, friend];
   str = [str stringByAppendingString:singleObjectTemplate];

   if(i<2)
        str = [str stringByAppendingString:@", "];
}

NSString* validJsonTemplate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"A\":[%@]}", str];
```

Comment: how to use `validJsonTemplate` in for loop to set values?

Comment: `NSString* validJsonTemplate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{"A":[%@]}", str];` has a syntax error